# Why won't this create multiple sets of random numbers?

Tags: java

Ok so the objective is to generate 6 random numbers per line/row. With x number of rows (set by the user via UserInput). Each row MUST have unique numbers (non-duplicated numbers). I'm pretty sure the numbers are unique, however I can't seem to get it to have multiple rows, and I cannot figure out for the life of me what part is preventing multiple rows.

```
package rtg;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class Array {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name;
    int noTickets;
    int[] numbers = new int[6];
    Set<Integer> randomNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    Random rand = new Random();



    int ticketCount = 1;



    System.out.println("Please input your name");
    name = UserInput.readString();
    System.out.println("Please input the number of tickets you want");
    noTickets = UserInput.readInt();
    System.out.println("___________________________________________\n___________________________________________");
    System.out.println("___________________________________________\n___________________________________________");


    System.out.println("Name: " +name+ "\nNumber of Tickets: " +noTickets+ "\nNumbers: ");

    for (ticketCount = 1; ticketCount <= noTickets; ++ticketCount){

        while (randomNumbers.size() < 6) {
            randomNumbers.add(rand.nextInt(50) + 1);
        }

        int i = 0;
        for (Integer n : randomNumbers) {
            numbers[i++] = n;
        }   



        System.out.print( Arrays.toString(numbers) + "\n");
    }

}
```

}

**EDIT** Thanks a lot everyone, I finally got there, turns out I put the array in the wrong place (it was outside the for loop so only made 1 set of random numbers) Fixed it now. Next challange; having a comparison program to scan 90+ sets of 6 unique numbers, and comparing if any of them match a different set (per row/set >.<)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can stuff random integers into a `Set<Integer>` until it has six elements:

```
Set<Integer> randomNumbers = new HashSet<>();
Random rand = new Random();
while (randomNumbers.size() < 6) {
    randomNumbers.add(rand.nextInt(50) + 1);
}
```

Alternatively, you can generate the numbers 1-50, shuffle them, and pick any six elements:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(50); // known capacity
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; ++i) { numbers.add(i); }
Collections.shuffle(numbers);
List<Integer> sixRandomNumbers = numbers.subList(0, 6);
```

The first solution does extra work whenever there is a collision; this extra work goes up the greater the ratio is of desired to total numbers. The second does extra work by having to deal with all 50 numbers; the extra work goes down the greater the ratio is of desired to total numbers. It's an interesting question where the cross-over point is.

**EDIT** (Responding to the edit to the original question) After you use one of the above methods to generate six distinct, random numbers, you need to put them into the variables you are going to use. One way (say, using the first method) is as follows:

```
int[] numbers = new int[6];
Set<Integer> randomNumbers = new HashSet<>();
Random rand = new Random();
while (randomNumbers.size() < 6) {
    randomNumbers.add(rand.nextInt(50) + 1);
}
System.out.println("Six random numbers: " + randomNumbers.toString());

// if you need them as an `int` array:
int i = 0;
for (Integer n : randomNumbers) {
    numbers[i++] = n;
}
```

The `numbers` array replaces your variables `number1`, ..., `number6`.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I think this has sorted it (I will do a few more checks but no duplicates so far). Just a quick request, would it be possible to explain what Set<Integer> and HashSet actually do? (I'd like to know for future reference :)

Also, slightly different question but related, if I were to input a series of 6 numbers manually (multiple rows also) would it be possible using this method, to check if any number matches another list? (IE I put in 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 on one row, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 on another row, and want to check if any numbers match 10, 4, 30, 12, 41, 9 etc?)

Comment: Erm...didn't work. Where abouts do I place this code out of interest (I've got it positioned at the top with the String Variable 'name' )

Comment: @Josh - What didn't work? (You can edit your question and post the revised code below the original post, if that's necessary to explain what's still wrong.) Regarding your second query--I suggest posting that as a new question.

Comment: @Josh - You can place my suggested code in a method that returns a `Collection<Integer>`. Then call the method whenever you need six random integers. (If you're going to use it more than once, you might want to make the `Random` a class field rather than creating a new one at each call.)

Comment: @Josh - I see you're still generating `number1` through `number6` the old way. You're supposed to replace that with just pulling out the six numbers from the set. (You can iterate over the set to get each element in turn.)

Comment: How would I call the sets into a println then? (I've never worked with/used sets before haha)

Comment: @Josh - I added some sample code. You can use `System.out.print()` (not `println()`) to print each number in a `for` loop; alternatively, you can convert to an `int[]` as I showed and then use `Arrays.toString(numbers)` to convert to a string for printing.

Comment: Ok nearly there I think. I've got it printing the randomNumbers variable, yet its only 1 set of random numbers. And I need as many numbers as the user inputs (originally this was done via the `int noTickets` variable, using the for loop)

Comment: Figured it out, I had array in the wrong place (it was outside the for loop so was only creating 1 set) Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a data type which allows you to check if the `int` has already been created.  For example, adding them to an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(numbers.size() < 6) {
    int num = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
    if(!numbers.contains(num)) {
        numbers.add(num);
    }
}
```

Of course, as @sanbhat says in the comments, you can use a `Set<Integer>` and avoid the `if()` conditional entirely in the loop.  However I thought this would be more intuitive for a beginner who doesn't know that the `Set` API will not add a duplicate element.

Comment: instead you can use `Set<Integer>`

Comment: EXACTLY the solution I was going to suggest! Josh, please note that once you follow this (correct) solution, you will have to keep in mind that the list contains `Integer`s, not `int`s.  this WILL make a difference!

Comment: @RussellUhl It likely won't make much of a difference due to autounboxing and such.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Well I meant if he at some point wants to compare the values, since (if I recall correctly - my info may be outdated or flat wrong) an int cannot be directly compared to an Integer type, since an Integer is an object and an int is not.  Is that correct?

Comment: @RussellUhl Actually, you can compare an `Integer` with an `int`.  But you raise a good point when comparing `Integer`s to other `Integer`s.

Comment: @JeffGohlke ahh THAT's what it was.  Can't directly compare Integer to Integer.  Thanks for that clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Save a sorted list or more efficiently a set of the previously chosen values and check your current selection against the previous ones, if it was previously chosen try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the valid range of your random numbers and if the size of that range is not prohibitive, one simple algorithm would be as follows:

- Create an array with a size equal to your number range
- Consecutively fill your array with the numbers in your number range
- Iterate through the list an arbitrarily large number of times; generate two pseudorandom numbers that are within your array indices, and swap the two elements at those indices

After the iteration is complete, you will have an array of uniquely represented numbers that are all within your number range that appear in a random order.  This nearly exactly simulates what happens when one shuffles a deck of cards.

You can then write a simple method to consecutively pop numbers out of your array each time it is called.

An advantage of this algorithm is that it can be implemented as an array of primitives, eg. int[], without any need for the Java Collections API.